# invoking javascript function on a server response in flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, web-applications

I have a flask application https://github.com/sameermahajan/PaadasMLFlaskApp I want to start the execution right away hence I have my paadas() function executing right away at "/" URL. It also needs to return a response (as you can see in the code) so that the returned audio gets played in the client browser. However when the control returns to the client it should automatically start executing javascript function startRecording (in my static/js/app.js that you can see in my repo). How can I do that? As I understand I need to probably need to have an html (like what I have put in templates/index.html in my repo) that specifies my javascript and return render_template from my starting function. However this approach has a problem that I cannot start my execution right away (and probably need to provide a button to click to get started or something). Also I didn't find a way where I can return a response as well as invoke a javascript function as I need.

I would further need help with recorder (that I have used in my javascript) to automatically stop recording (on silence or some timeout) rather than an explicit press of the stop button and send the file to the server for further processing. But I guess I will worry about that later.

Based on a couple of posts I put the following in my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Paadas</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Welcome to Padaas</h1>
   <audio controls autoplay>
     <source src="{{source}}" type="audio/wav">
     Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
return render_template("index.html", source=generate(files))
```

in my python code. However the audio control that gets rendered is disabled and does not play anything. Any ideas?